# Airflow Jinja renders list of integer strings as int tuple

Tags: airflow, jinja2, airflow-2.x

I currently have the following DAG structure:

```
with airflow.DAG(
  'example_dag',
  render_template_as_native_obj=True,
  params={
      'array': ['1', '2', '3'],
  },
) as dag:
```

where I use p like this:

```
  dummy_job = job_operator.JobOperator(
      task_id='dummy_job',
      job_name='dummy_job',
      job_vars={
          'p': '{{ params.array | join(",") }}',
      },
  )
```

I would expect the value of 'p' in job_vars to be rendered as "1,2,3" but instead it was turned into a tuple (1,2,3), not even a string.

I tried to write a complex jinja expression to convert it like:

```
          'p': """
                {% set p1 = [] %}
                {% for b in params.p %}
                {% set p1 = p1.append( b ) %}
                {% endfor %}
                {{ p1 | join(",") }}""",
```

But the result was something weird: `'\n \n \n \n \n \n \n \n \n 1,2,3'`. I'm completely lost was to why Airflow or Jinja would convert it this way or what to do to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

By default, Airflow renders Jinja templates as strings. However, you've configured `render_template_as_native_obj=True` which renders to Python objects (tuple in your example). So, remove `render_template_as_native_obj` or set it to `False`, and Airflow will render your template to a string.

Comment: Thanks for the response. However render_template_as_native_obj=True is also needed for other params where a boolean or list type is required. Is there a way to force a type on the param so the Airflow engine does not convert it at its own discretion?

Comment: Unfortunately no, at this moment `render_template_as_native_obj` can only be configured on DAG-level.